# Ruby Array Storing Different Type Following Map

Tags: ruby, dictionary

I have a function that takes an equation as an array of strings and (I am hoping) replaces any known variables with their values (puts statements are only included for debugging):

```
  def replace_known_variables
    @equation_array.map! do |x|
      for known_var in @known_variables
        puts "@equation_array is initially #@equation_array"
        if known_var.full_name == x
          x = known_var.value.to_f
          puts "x is now #{x}"
        else
          x = x
          puts "x is still #{x}"
        end
      end
    end
    puts "@equation_array is now #@equation_array"
  end
```

This is probably not the "Ruby way" to handle this situation, so open to any advice there, but my question is, when I actually run this, it looks like x is properly being set, but when all's said and done, my @equation_array ends up holding instances of the class used by known_var (a Variable class I created) rather than the strings I'd expect. It looks to me like x is actually being stored back as the instance. For example:

```
@equation_array is initially ["amperage", "*", "resistance"]
x is now 12.0
@equation_array is initially ["amperage", "*", "resistance"]
x is still 12.0
@equation_array is initially [[#<Variable:0x000001c28755c490 @abbrev="i", @full_name="amperage", @unit="A", @value="12">, #<Variable:0x000001c28745a060 @abbrev="r", @full_name="resistance", @unit="Ohms", @value="2200">], "*", "resistance"]
x is still *
@equation_array is initially [[#<Variable:0x000001c28755c490 @abbrev="i", @full_name="amperage", @unit="A", @value="12">, #<Variable:0x000001c28745a060 @abbrev="r", @full_name="resistance", @unit="Ohms", @value="2200">], "*", "resistance"]
x is still *
@equation_array is initially [[#<Variable:0x000001c28755c490 @abbrev="i", @full_name="amperage", @unit="A", @value="12">, #<Variable:0x000001c28745a060 @abbrev="r", @full_name="resistance", @unit="Ohms", @value="2200">], [#<Variable:0x000001c28755c490 @abbrev="i", @full_name="amperage", @unit="A", @value="12">, #<Variable:0x000001c28745a060 @abbrev="r", @full_name="resistance", @unit="Ohms", @value="2200">], "resistance"]
x is still resistance
@equation_array is initially [[#<Variable:0x000001c28755c490 @abbrev="i", @full_name="amperage", @unit="A", @value="12">, #<Variable:0x000001c28745a060 @abbrev="r", @full_name="resistance", @unit="Ohms", @value="2200">], [#<Variable:0x000001c28755c490 @abbrev="i", @full_name="amperage", @unit="A", @value="12">, #<Variable:0x000001c28745a060 @abbrev="r", @full_name="resistance", @unit="Ohms", @value="2200">], "resistance"]
x is now 2200.0
@equation_array is now [[#<Variable:0x000001c28755c490 @abbrev="i", @full_name="amperage", @unit="A", @value="12">, #<Variable:0x000001c28745a060 @abbrev="r", @full_name="resistance", @unit="Ohms", @value="2200">], [#<Variable:0x000001c28755c490 @abbrev="i", @full_name="amperage", @unit="A", @value="12">, #<Variable:0x000001c28745a060 @abbrev="r", @full_name="resistance", @unit="Ohms", @value="2200">], [#<Variable:0x000001c28755c490 @abbrev="i", @full_name="amperage", @unit="A", @value="12">, #<Variable:0x000001c28745a060 @abbrev="r", @full_name="resistance", @unit="Ohms", @value="2200">]]
```

I've tried a couple of things (explicitly specifying to_ types in all assignments, removing the to_f in the value save), but no go, and I'm basically just not sure what I am doing wrong (apart from possibly a convoluted methodology overall).  I could hack around it by creating a temporary hash or something, but I'd rather understand what's wrong with my intended flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"If case"** is the expression in Ruby, that returns the result. Since you use map!, it replaces the returned value with the original value. So try the below code.

```
def replace_known_variables
  @equation_array.map! do |x|
    known_var = @known_variables.find { |var| var.full_name == x }
    known_var ? known_var.value.to_f : x
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I would probably build a lookup hash that maps the variable names to their respective (floating point) values:

```
@values = @known_variables.to_h { |v| [v.full_name, v.value.to_f] }
#=> {"amperage"=>12.0, "resistance"=>2200.0}
```

With this hash, the replacement is almost trivial:

```
@equation_array = ['amperage', '*', 'resistance']

@equation_array.map { |x| @values.fetch(x, x) }
#=> [12.0, "*", 2200.0]
```

[`Hash#fetch`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) returns the value for the key which is given as the first argument. If the key is not found (e.g. `'*'`), it returns the second argument which is simply the key itself so that `'*'` remains `'*'`.